# Excecuting Junit test classes in Order

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have three junit test classes - ClassA, ClassB, ClassC which have indiviual test methods in each class.

My requirement is i should run ClassB test class first and then ClassA and then ClassC.

Is possible. i am junit Junit5

Comment: how long [did you search](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order)?

Comment: I am asking a class level of priority not a method level. @Eugene how long did you took to read this question?

Comment: this requirement means that your tests do not run in isolation - which means you have a much bigger problem.

Comment: @Eugene yes my requirement is like that one class is dependent on another. Even in production it runs the same one step is dependent on other.